# Is there a way to modify '&:before/:after' to give a dynamic property?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

A styled-component that has `&:before` attribute that I want to give access to a dynamic color property. But I'm lost to how to apply that.

I've Tried passing the props to *`<Hover />`* and it works. But the Triangle in `&:before` cannot access that.

```
const Hover = styled.div`
  padding:7px;
  margin: -102px auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 15px; 
  border-width: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left:-15px;
  z-index:10;

   &:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 10px solid ;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid ;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  left: 19px;
  bottom: -19px;
  z-index:10;

}
`;
```

**As a single styled-component the following class is:**

```
class MarkerHover extends Component {

    render() {
        const {color, children}= this.props
        return (


            <Hover style={{backgroundColor: color }}>
           {...children}
                </Hover>


        );
    }
}

export default MarkerHover;
```

I expect to have a whole colored Window after successfully passing the color props to the `&:before` division.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation of Styled Components states (see https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) you can read passed props:

```
const Hover = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

when you pass them like this:

```
<Hover color="#f00" />
```

You can use that same prop in your pseudo-element as well:

```
const Hover = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color};
  &::before {
    background: ${props => props.color};
  }
`;
```

So don't use the `style` attribute on your styled component, but pass regular props.

If you want to apply a CSS rule only after a certain condition, you can do that like this:

```
const Hover = styled.div`
  color: #ccc;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    padding: 16px;
    ${props => props.withBg ? `background-color: ${props.withBg}` : ''}
  }
`;
```

With background:

```
<Hover withBg="#f00" />
```

Without background:

```
<Hover />
```

Comment: i Dont understand to how to pass the props in between css lines. i tried including
``` const{color}=this.props ``` at the top of the code and did what you said. still no result. why?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to 'add' an extra rule to the CSS? If so, I've added a snippet to my answer!